# Using cryptography to protect database integrity

Tags: integrity, siphash

I'm designing a micro-services system where each service manages some set of entities (User, Account, e.g).

I want to be able to verify the authenticity of entity identifiers (e.g User-Id and Account-Id), to make sure the identifier was actually produced by service and not some random data a user produced.

For example, the Account-Service has a Create-Account method that accepts a User-Id (the owner of the account), I want to avoid going to the User-Service in order to check if the User-Id actually exist (or using database foreign keys). The identifiers are 64-bit integers.

Two additional requirements are for the cryptography algorithm is to be very fast and produce short as possible ciphertext/MAC. I don't care if the 64-bit identifiers would be exposed.

Authenticated encryption with sharing the secret between the services would produce a very long string and would be too slow.

I'm considering SipHash but I'm not sure if it is secure enough for this purpose, maybe the 128-bit version of SipHash?

Any other algorithm or method to achieve this?

Comment: To me this looks more like software development question, not a cryptography question. If you don't check if a User-Id already exists, there is a possibility to get multiple duplicates. Thousands of users can try to use the same User-Id to create an account. It is not clear how do you want to use hashing to prevent reusing User-Id without checking these User-Ids. That's why it is not clear why this question is placed here, not at SO.

Comment: I don't want to check for duplicates, I want to check that the user-id was sourced from my system and not just a random number. I don't want the account-service to query the user-service for validity of the user-id, so I want the account-service to be able to verify that the user-id was actually sourced from the user-service. An expensive way would be to use authenticated encryption and sharing the key between the two services.

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Now the question is clear. 1) Why don't you want to use some broadly used approaches like JWT? 2) Parsing of HTTP request, de-serialization of request data from JSON/XML to Java/C#/Python/PHP, performing some operations on database, serializing of data to HTTP response can take much more time (10x - 100x) than validating the hash. Why do you care about performance of hashing?

Comment: It is only for identifiers, not for tokens, identifiers should be somewhat presentable and therefore short (as securly possible). JWT will yield very long string. So if I would use base32 encoding, 64bit identifier + 64 MAC (siphash) would yield 26 chars string (for example: wie2leebie5uyooxohjoaxaich), which is somewhat presentable. The question is, is siphash strong enough for this?

Comment: Or I must use a strong MAC algorithm, and if a stronger algorithm is required, is sighash 128bit will be strong enough? is there any other 128bit MAC algorithm I can use?

Comment: I cannot decide it for you. It depends. Here are some questions that can help. 1) What can be the consequences (the price) to you in case an attacker finds a hash collision and makes you accept some ID that actually doesn't exist? Is it serious or there will be no serious consequences? If the latter, why hashing at all? 2) What is the price of having other performance, e.g. compared to AES CMAC? Will using other algorithm mean that you have to order 2x more hardware and thus increase you costs? 3) What is the price of having longer messages?

Comment: 4) What resources needs an attacker to brute-force the MAC/hash? How much CPU and RAM power is needed over how long time? E.g. one 4-Core CPU x 2 days work or 1000 4-core CPUs over 2 years? How much can it cost the attacker? 5) What can be benefits to attacker if he brute-forced some hash for some ID? Are benefits to the attacker comparable with the price to brute-force?

Comment: Depending on answers you can conclude that risks are low, consequences in case of successful brute-forcing are acceptable, and thus that SipHash is a perfect fit. Or you can conclude that potential risks are not acceptable and you need other hash/MAC or may be even other service design (e.g. use JWT, or use ID validation by calling another service).

Comment: thanks, that is very helpful